# Android: Cannot Open Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I did an entire morning of research. Adding `OpenOrCreateDatabase` in the constructor of the Helper didn't work, adding permissions in the manifest didn't either. I also tried reinstalling the app.
Here's my Helper class:

```
public class UserGameData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String DB_NAME ="userdata.db";
    public static final int DB_VER = 1;


    public UserGameData(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME, null,DB_VER);
        int i =0; // the error is this line for some reason??
        context.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,DB_VER,null);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GameData (Character TEXT NOT NULL,Unlocked BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, IntroVn BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false, EndVn BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,HighScore int not null DEFAULT 0,Unlocks text not null DEFAULT yellow,UnlockCondition INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 50, PRIMARY KEY (Character))");
        db.execSQL(create);
        init();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


    }
```

Here's the activity that uses the helper

```
public class Select extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select);
        UserGameData db= new UserGameData(this); //error occurred here
    }
    }
```

The error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.reimu.buttonchange, PID: 21383
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.reimu.buttonchange/com.example.reimu.buttonchange.Select}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:213)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:197)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:709)
                      at com.example.reimu.buttonchange.UserGameData.<init>(UserGameData.java:23)
                      at com.example.reimu.buttonchange.Select.onCreate(Select.java:37)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I also tried hard-coding the path

```
public static final String DB_NAME ="/data/data/com.example.reimu.buttonchange/databases/userdata.db3userdata.db";
```

Comment: Why are you trying to access `userdata.db3userdata.db`? your db name is `userdata.db`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `context.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,DB_VER,null)` in `SQLiteOpenHelper` is incorrect and not needed. As seen in the stacktrace, the error occurs there. Possibly because the second argument is 1 which means [`MODE_WORLD_READABLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) to [`openOrCreateDatabase()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)).

Remove that call.

To create a database file with `SQLiteOpenHelper`, call `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` on the helper.

Comment: Ohh thanks! It fixed that, now I am getting `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1`, for  `Boolean result = ((db.query("GameData", new String[]{"Unlocked"}, "Character=?", new String[]{name}, null, null, null)).getInt(0)==1);` . Any idea why?

Comment: You need to call one of the `moveTo...()` methods such as `moveToFirst()` to position the cursor on a valid row.